# Javascript loading JSON data from three files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, promise

I've got a problem and I cannot find a solution anywhere.

I'vo got 3 files with classes in PHP that return me values in JSON.

I wanted to change this return into JAVAscript. The problem is that to download this values from the second and the third PHP file I need to send the value that I download from the first one.
I try like this:

```
$.when(dev)
        .then(function(dataDev){
            dataDev = JSON.parse(dataDev);
            $.each(dataDev,function(key,val){
                $.when($.post("PHP/His.php",{menu : 0, devId : val.id }))
                        .then(function(his){
                $.when($.post("PHP/Com.php",{menu : 0, devId : val.id }))
                                .then(function(com){

                                    console.log(his);
                    console.log(com);
                })
            his =JSON.parse(his);

                })

            })
```

And I don't know how to get data from this two files by promisses with put there parameters from first JSON data

Please help if you can.

Comment: Why are you wrapping all promises with a `$.when`? that's just cargo cult boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

hm.. I made something like this:

```
var devPost = $.post("PHP/Dev.php",{menu: 0});
$.when(devPost)
        .done(function(devData){
          var hisPost;
          var comPost;
          $.each(devices,function(key,val){
                hisPost = $.post("PHP/Hist.php",{menu : 0, deviceId : val.id });
                comPost = $.post("PHP/Com.php",{menu : 0, deviceId : val.id });

                $.when(histPost,conPost)
                   .done(function(hisData,butData){
                      //do all with devData,hisData,conData.
                    })
         })
        })
```